# Why is my FeaturePlot expression scale from -1 to 2 and how to make it from 0 to 2?

Tags: r, plot, seurat

I tried to make a feature plot to check some marker genes in my clusters and used the code:
`pericyte<-FeaturePlot(sunion, reduction = "umap", features = c("Mefesk4", "Vtn", "Colec11", "Abcc9", "Myo1v", "Cooh7", "Heyl", "Kcnj8", "Gnb4", "Rgs5"))`

The code works and I can see a cluster expressing these genes lighting up. However, some plots had their colour scale from 0 to 2 while others have from -1 to 2. Plots with -1 to 2 scale are giving all clusters a blue hue, while in 0 to 2 scale non-expressing clusters are gray.

I'd like to have all plots use 0 to 2 scale but how do I define the scale? I tried to add  `keep.scale = "all"` into the code but that only made all scales being from -1 to 2.

Answer (score 0):

Without actual data it is a bit hard to give a good solution, but perhaps you can use the following two functions to scale any matrix into a range of your liking (and also revert them back if necessary). This way you might be able to prepare your data before plotting:

```
scale.2<-function(b,frange=c(0,1)){
  std<-(b-min(b))/(max(b)-min(b))
  scl<-std*(frange[2]-frange[1]) + frange[1]
  return(list(scl=scl,scale_range=frange,minmax_original=c(min(b),max(b))))
}

unscale<-function(scl,minmax_original){
  frange<-c(min(scl),max(scl))
  std<-(scl-frange[1])/(frange[2]-frange[1])
  b<-std*(minmax_original[2]-minmax_original[1]) + minmax_original[1]
  return(b)
}
```

And here is an example how it works:

```
original<-matrix(1:9,nrow=3,byrow = T)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9
```

Scaling into a range [0..255]

```
scaled<-scale.2(original,frange = c(0,255))

$scl
        [,1]    [,2]    [,3]
[1,]   0.000  31.875  63.750
[2,]  95.625 127.500 159.375
[3,] 191.250 223.125 255.000

$scale_range
[1]   0 255

$minmax_original
[1] 1 9
```

And restoring original data from this:

```
unscale(scaled$scl,scaled$minmax_original)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
[3,]    7    8    9
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this before calling FeaturePlot

```
DefaultAssay(sunion) = "RNA"
```

Comment: i think the negative values come from the scaled integrated data

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).